# Getting unexpected response from Laravel factory() causing Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

A Laravel `factory()` function inside a `factory()->create()->each()` is giving a very unexpected result. The function is returning a huge array full of strings and sub-arrays, when var_dumping it inside the console I have to ctrl+c to stop it from rendering the result else it keeps on running (haven't seen the end of the array). When executing `php artisan DB:seed` I'll the following result: `Segmentation fault (Core dumped)`.

The content inside the array looks like data from the Faker library.

Does anyone has an idea of where this can possibly come from?

- I have minimized my code down to only the factory for the Model I want to insert in my DB. This ofcourse still is giving me the same result.
- I have var_dumped the class name from the object returned, the object returned is from the class "Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder". As expected.
- Inside the SubscriptionFactory.php file I have commented out everything inside the `$factory->define()` function.

#### Code

The code below is giving me the never ending array.

```php
factory(App\SubscriptionGroup::class, 3)
->create()
->each(function ($subscriptionGroup)
{
    $test = factory(App\Subscription::class);
    var_dump($test);
});
```

The code below is my SubscriptionFactory php file.

```php
use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Subscription::class, function (Faker $faker)
{

    $minAge = null;
    if (rand(0, 100) > 75) {
        $minAge = $faker->randomElement([12, 16, 18]);
    }

    $maxAge = null;
    if (rand(0, 100) > 75) {
        $maxAge = $faker->randomElement([21, 35, 50]);
    }

    $duration = 1;
    if (rand(0, 100) > 25) {
        $duration = $faker->randomElement([1, 6, 12, 24]);
    }

    $paidByMember = null;
    if (rand(0, 100) > 90) {
        $paidByMember = true;
    } elseif (rand(0, 100) > 90) {
        $paidByMember = false;
    }

    $tokenPeriod       = \App\TokenPeriod::find(rand(1, 7));
    $directDebitPeriod = \App\DirectDebitPeriod::find(rand(1, 3));

    $unlimitedAccess         = $faker->boolean(10);
    $periodicTokens          = 0;
    $transferableTokenPeriod = 0;

    if ( ! $unlimitedAccess) {
        $periodicTokens          = $faker->randomElement([1, 2, 4]);
        $transferableTokenPeriod = rand(0, 4);
    }

    $name = implode(' ', $faker->words(rand(1, 2)));

    return [
        'status'                    => 'published',
        'name'                      => $name,
        'min_age'                   => $minAge,
        'max_age'                   => $maxAge,
        'membership_duration'       => $duration,
        'membership_duration_in'    => 'months',
        'available_date'            => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
        'withdraw_date'             => null,
        'visibility_order'          => 1,
        'paid_by_member'            => $paidByMember,
        'unlimited_access'          => $unlimitedAccess,
        'periodic_tokens'           => $periodicTokens,
        'transferable_token_period' => $transferableTokenPeriod,
        'check_in_access_type_id'   => 1,
        'token_period_id'           => $tokenPeriod->id,
        'direct_debit_period_id'    => $directDebitPeriod->id
    ];
});
```

#### Result

The SubscriptionGroup factory is running as expected and fills the database accordingly. But the Subscription factory is giving the wrong result. See the piece of the resulting array below.

```
...
["de schuitjes"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(3) "van"
}
["schuitjes van"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(3) "den"
}
["den ponton-steiger"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(3) "bij"
}
["ponton-steiger bij"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(9) "Nijmegen."
}
["bij Nijmegen."]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(2) "En"
}
["Nijmegen. En"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(2) "nu"
}
["nu spraken"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
  string(2) "ze"
}
["ze over"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
  string(3) "z'n"
[1]=>
  string(2) "'t"
}
...
```

### EDIT

The code below also seems to cause the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. So it seems the error doesn't come from `factory(App\Subscription::class)`, but rather the subscriptions() relation inside SubscriptionGroup. Which makes it even stranger because that's just a simple hasMany relationship.

```php
factory(App\SubscriptionGroup::class)
->create()
->each(function ($subscriptionGroup)
{
        $subscriptionGroup->subscriptions();
});
```

The subscriptions() relation inside the `SubscriptionGroup` class:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own problem.

For certain models I had created an abstract class with a $scope attribute. The attribute had a default value 'public'. After removing the default value from this attribute everything worked.

I've moved the default value for this attribute to the constructor method.